# pass variable from a dom element to onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a text from a DOM element to an onclick function. So the text will be a parameter

I tried

```
$("body").append(
  "<input type='submit' value='Submit Answers' onclick=displayImages(" + 
  $('#hidden_number').text() +  ");'>")
```

but this gives me `$('#hidden_number').text()` as undefined , but if I run `$('#hidden_number').text()` from the console i get a value.

Is it not possible to pass a parameter this way?

More code

The html page looks like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/js/self_control.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").append( "<input type='submit' value='Submit Answers' onclick=displayImages( $('#hidden_number').text());'>");
});
</script>

<label for="subID">Subject ID:</label>
<input type="text" id="subID" name="subID"/>
<br><br>
<div> Please enter your subject </div>
<br>
<body>
</body>
```

the file self_control.js has the displayImages function

```
function displayImages(number){
    $('body').toggleClass('blackBody'); // set the color of the expr background to black
    console.log(number)
}
```

the way that I load the page and the number to the hidden array is:

```
function loadQuestionForm(number){
    $.get("core/questionForm0.html", function(data) {
                $("body").html(data);
                var next_img = number + 1 ;
                console.log(next_img);
                $("body").append("<div id='hide_nubmer' style='display: none;'>"+ next_img +"</div>")
    });
```

Comment: This definitely works, but why would you need this here? Can't you just make this a variable in `displayImages`?

Comment: 1. It is possible if you use more quotes and the hidden number exists at the time of the append. 2. instead remove the quotes and do `$("body").append(
  "<input type='submit' value='Submit Answers' onclick='displayImages( 
  $('#hidden_number').text())'>")`

Comment: could you post the code along with the html.

Comment: This shows as <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers" onclick="displayImages(" $('#hidden_number').text());'="">

Comment: maybe $('#hidden_number') is not loaded on the DOM yet at the append time

Comment: Added code about the way I load the number to the dom

Comment: `hidden_number`? - looks like your id is `hide_nubmer`

Comment: I am such an idiot:\

Comment: Why is your onClick=displayImages not quoted? Also, why not just do $("body").append( '<input/>', {type: 'submit', value: 'submit answers', onClick: '...'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("body").append("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answers' onclick=displayImages(" + $('#hidden_number').text() + ");>")

function displayImages(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidden_number">5</div>
```

Comment: still showing
<input type="submit" value="Submit Answers" onclick="displayImages();">

Comment: and <div id="hide_nubmer" style="display: none;">3</div>

Answer (score 0):

i think it looks like just a typo?

```
$("body").append("<div id='hide_nubmer' style='display: none;'>"+ next_img +"</div>")
```

should have the `id` be `hidden_number`?

```
function loadQuestionForm(number){
    $.get("core/questionForm0.html", function(data) {
                $("body").html(data);
                var next_img = number + 1 ;
                console.log(next_img);
                $("body").append("<div id='hidden_number' style='display: none;'>"+ next_img +"</div>")
    });
```

Comment: for some reason even when I fix this <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers" onclick="displayImages();"> is still empty

I know for sure that now the div is good <div id="hide_nubmer" style="display: none;">3</div>

Comment: not sure i understand that, still saying `hide_nubmer`?